# Update Asset Channel ID of a YouTube Asset

Tags: youtube-api

We got many assets where ChannelID and AssetChannelID fields are blank. Mostly due to a history of us creating reference files for Content ID for copyright purposes.

**How can I and assign the reference file/asset to a channel?**

I think I've seen myself blind on the API documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I check the YouTube API documentation and I can't find any guide there on how to get your problem. Please check this [link](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/api/asset_youtube.html) and [this](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/api/asset_channel.html) if it can help you.

Comment: I wanted to see if YouTube API Support was monitoring here as I've previously been given indicator they are. I'm on with them by email...

Answer (score 0):

Two weeks later...

Here's the final conclusion: **Not supported**

> asset channel id is decided when the reference file is uploaded to a
>   channel as a watchable video, created an asset out of it, and claim
>   the upload as licensed. It is not suppose to be changed arbitrarily
>   afterwards, even by the CO owner.

Even though not the answer I wanted, it is what it is and sometimes the answer is that it's a no go.